# How can I delete a changeset from my Mercurial repository's log without affecting the working directory?

Tags: mercurial

My log looks like 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 (tip). I want to delete 2 from the log without affecting the current state of my working directory.

I accomplished this somewhat by:

1. Make new repository from copy of working directory. Call this B
2. Make 1 the parent of 3 in repository A
3. hg strip -r 2
4. Paste the repository history from B on to the end of my existing repository A
5. hg update

So now the log looks like 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 (tip from copied repository) and the files are correct, but I'd rather the log look like 1 -> 3 -> 4 (tip)

Answer (score 0):

You should really try to avoid editing history in the general case -- having an accurate history is usually more important than having a perfect one.  That said, you can probably do what you want by combining 2 with 3 using the [histedit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) extension's `fold` sub-commmand.  You already have `histedit`, it ships with Mercurial, but you have to enable it.

Comment: That does not completely remove the changeset though, right? Histedit fold just folds the changes from both into one. I need the record of the changes deleted.

Comment: It removes the changeset in that the the log is shorter by one, that hash is gone, and the commit comment and metadata are gone.  It doesn't remove the changes that were in the changeset -- because unless they're already completely undone in a subsequent changeset it would change the working directory.  If they _are_ completely undone in a subsequent changeset then you'd need to remove (or fold together into nothing) both the thing you regret and the place where you reversed it -- you can't have the reversal still there w/o the change that it's reversing.